# 2 database connections in one file - how will it impact performance?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hello i have one simple question, so this is my dbConnect.php file

```
<?php 
require_once 'enviorements/qa-env.php';
require_once 'vendor/joshcam/mysqli-database-class/MysqliDb.php';

$mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
$db = new MysqliDb($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);

mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, 'utf8');
?>
```

As you can see i have $mysqli and $db variables, at beginning i was just using $mysqli, but later i discovered [this awesome](https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class) PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class, and im wondering will this have impact on my performance since i have $db and $mysqli variables defined as db connections in one file.

Comment: Why do you need both, though? They seem to have the same host, user and database.

Comment: Well i need $mysqli for my old code, because i dont have time to refactor old stuff where i used $mysqli native functions, then as i told in question i discovered PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class and it have some awesome helper functions and at the moment i just use them because it makes life much easier for some tasks, so im just wondering will this cause any performance issues ?

Comment: Well, that class doesn't even `extend mysqli`, if it did, you could just use the same functions in one class as the parent class. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php - then you need just one object.

Comment: Im not sure if i totaly understand what are you trying to say, do you have patience to try explain me slightly better ?

Comment: What I'm saying is that if you have `class MysqliDb extends mysqli` instead of `class MysqliDb`, you can still use native MySQLi methods on your `$db` object - then you don't need the `$mysqli` object, as `$db` effectively is the `$mysqli` object, with some additions inside the `mysqlidb` class.

Comment: Great, thx for explanation i will try to see if it will work.

Comment: I have just tested this, and i can't use mysqli native function for example i have this error Call to undefined method MysqliDb::prepare()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
$db = new MysqliDb($mysqli);
```

According to documentaion MysqliDb can use existing mysqli object, so that answers my question and i hope this helps to someone.